# How add WordPress links/bookmarks programmatically?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, bookmarks

I have a function that is hooked to WordPress' scheduled cron jobs, that goes through some RSS feeds and adds links.

I can't seem to find a function that will add the links for me, so I have to write them myself using `$wpdb`. The only problem then is that `wp_list_bookmarks()` won't recognize them because I don't have a relationship between the link and the link category (which I've understand that has something to do with the `wp_term_relationships` and `wp_term_taxonomy` tables to do.

Here's what the query code do so far (which apparently not work):

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."links (link_url, link_name, link_updated) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($item->get_permalink())."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->get_title())."', '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')");
$last_insert_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."term_relationships VALUES ('".$last_insert_id."', '".$category_id."', '0'");
$wpdb->query("UPDATE ".$wpdb->prefix."term_taxonomy SET count = count+1 WHERE term_id = '".$category_id."'");
```

But I can't figure out how to make this work, anyone else knows how to programmatically add links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wp_insert_link()` is what you want. It's in `wp-admin/includes/bookmark.php`

We've bounced around on what to name links. Blogroll, Bookmarks, Links, etc — ergo the naming mismatch.

Comment: Fantastic! But where do I define the link category? As far as I see, the function checks if `$linkcategory` is set, but the function won't take the link category, or can I just provide the link category in the link data array?

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_insert_link()`. I'm using WP 2.9b1.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. I didn't find an "`add_bookmarks`" for example in Wordpress function reference.

To accomplish your goal, I would read get_bookmarks [source code](http://lab.yukei.net/wp-code/wp-includes/bookmark.php.source.html#l97) to understand exactly how are the tables implemented and write a function (`add_bookmark` for example) in functions.php.

I do believe that if you create this function you should get in touch with Wordpress developers since it's something interesting to add to Wordpress core in next versions.